# Tiled CIFilter returning nil every time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

I'm trying to get a Reflected Tile filter to work on iOS and I get nil back every time. Does anyone have any ideas why this would be? I can get every other CIFilter to work fine (so far). But I'm stuck on the tiles. Any idea?

```
func tile() -> UIImage?{
    
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let tile = CIFilter.fourfoldReflectedTile()
    tile.inputImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "dog")!)
    tile.angle = 0
    tile.center = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)
    tile.width = 20
    tile.acuteAngle = 0

    if let output = tile.outputImage {
        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
          return  processedImage
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This filter returns an image with infinite extent (it repeats the image in tiles). You need to crop the `outputImage` to some finite extent when you want to render that into an image again:

```swift
let output = tile.outputImage?.cropped(to: <some CGRect>)
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much. I'm struggling to find documentation for specific filters. Do they exist? Or is it a matter of feeling in the dark?!

Comment: For anyone else having issues, also change this line...
 if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: tile.inputImage!.extent)

Comment: I can recommend the free app _Filter Magic_, available on the Mac App Store. You can play around with all the filters, and it also contains quite a lot of documentation.